# Why SetInterval stops executing after passing php string

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code:

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $starttime; ?>").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date("<?php echo $nowtime; ?>").getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = - countDownDate + now;
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hoursdiff = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

It executes and calculates time difference between 2 dates that are fetched from the DB. It's supposed to update the difference every second working as a **stopwatch** but for some reason it shows the difference once and interval function stops working.

But if I remove `"<?php echo $nowtime; ?>"` from 'now' variable, it starts working like a charm.

Comment: Make sure `$nowtime;` is defined and it is valid `date-time`

Comment: Check the generated code (right click on the page and "view source"). Does it look correct?

Comment: have you checked or dumped $starttime and $nowtime?

Comment: @B.Desai it is!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it is generating the way it's supposed to as far as I can tell....

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan yeah those values are okay

Comment: Want to share what the generated output looks like? We don't want to guess...

Comment: Thanks guys, i solved it by adding js function please check out my asnwe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply.

I decided to use javascript to update the time difference that i was fetching from the db. Specifically, I am refreshing a section of the page rather than the whole page. It works just like a stopwatch now.

1) Starts the counter

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:4567/home_controller/startcount">start count</a><br>
                <?php if (!empty($timer->start)){$date1=date_create($timer->start);
                $date2=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
                $days = $diff->format("%d");
                $hours = $diff->format("%h");
                $minutes = $diff->format("%i")/60;
                $seconds = $diff->format("%s")/360;
                $timediff = $hours+$minutes+$seconds;}
 ?>
```

2) Refreshes the section where time difference is being displayed.

```
<div id="scope"><?php if (!empty($timer->start)){echo $diff->format("%d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");} ?></div> <script type="text/javascript">
     var $scores = $("#scores");
setInterval(function () {$("#scope").load("http://127.0.0.1:4567/home_controller/ #scope");
}, 1000);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use php within the actual function for obtaining the current time ( now ) why not simply use the javascript method`Date().getTime()` ? The php variable would not have been updated after the page has loaded so the date function would constantly refer to the same time

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    <?php
        /* example date */
        $starttime='2017-08-20 14:30:30';

        echo "
            var countDownDate = new Date('$starttime').getTime();
        ";
    ?>

    (function(time){
        var now=new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hoursdiff = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        t=setTimeout( arguments.callee, time );

        if( distance <= 0 ){
            clearTimeout( t );
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    })(1000);
</script>
```

To achieve the constant polling of server time without using ajax long polling I think Server Sent Events would be ideal. The first script below is the server component used in SSE - it sends a formatted message back to the javascript client every X seconds, in this case every 1 second.

```
<?php

    /* sse-time.php */
    set_time_limit( 0 );
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', 1);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
    ob_end_clean();

    $sleep = 1; /* send message back every X seconds */
    $startdate = !empty( $_GET['start'] ) ? $_GET['start'] : false;
    $evt = !empty( $_GET['evt'] ) ? $_GET['evt'] : 'time';

    if( $startdate ){
        /* 
        utility function to send formatted response
        */
        function sse( $evtname='sse', $data=null, $retry=1000 ){
            if( !is_null( $data ) ){
                echo "event:".$evtname."\r\n";
                echo "retry:".$retry."\r\n";
                echo "data:" . json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS );
                echo "\r\n\r\n";
            }
        }
        /*
            Important to set correct headers
        */
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); 
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
        header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Events');

        /* Infinite loop */
        while( true ){
            if( connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL or connection_aborted() ) {
                break;
            }

            /* If the current date/time is greater than countdown target, exit loop */
            if( time() > $startdate ) break;

            /* construct the payload */
            $payload=array(
                'event'     =>  $evt,
                'date'      =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
                'start'     =>  $startdate
            );
            /* send the payload */
            call_user_func( 'sse', $evt, $payload );

            /* -- Send output -- */
            if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
            @flush();

            /* wait for defined period before repeating loop */
            sleep( $sleep );
        } //end infinite loop

        if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) {
            for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
            @ob_end_clean();
        }
    }
?>
```

The client side component is wrapped here in a basic html page to show how the wholoe thing works.

```
<?php
    /* countdown */
    $starttime='2017-08-21 10:58:30';
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SSE Countdown</title>
        <script>
            <?php
                echo " var countDownDate = new Date('$starttime').getTime();";
            ?>
            function bindEvtSource(){
                var evtname='time';
                var url='https://sentinel/assets/sse-time.php?start='+countDownDate+'&evt='+evtname;
                var demo=document.getElementById('demo');

                if ( !!window.EventSource ) {
                    var evtSource = new EventSource( url );

                    evtSource.addEventListener( 'error', function(e){
                        console.error('%o %s',e,e.type);
                    },false);

                    evtSource.addEventListener( evtname, function(e){
                        var json=JSON.parse(e.data);


                        var now=new Date( json.date ).getTime();
                        var distance = countDownDate - now;
                        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        var hoursdiff = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                        demo.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
                        if( distance <= 0 ){
                            evtSource.close();
                            demo.innerHTML='EXPIRED';
                        }
                    },false);
                } else {
                    demo.innerHTML='Server Sent Events are not supported in this browser';
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvtSource, false );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='demo'></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: problem is if I use javascript function for obtaining the current time, it uses client side time but I need to use server side time.

Comment: Ok - I understand. The obvious solution to my mind would be to use `Server Sent Events` - they naturally reconnect every second I believe if there is no infinite loop running server side so a very basic PHP script could send the server time back every second.

Comment: Thanks, i solved it by adding js function please check out my asnwer